# How to correctly load and call Javascript in WordPress child themes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I already searched several hours for [a](http://crunchify.com/genesis-framework-how-to-enqueue-scripts-and-css-into-child-theme/) [proper](http://wpsites.net/web-design/best-ways-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress/) [tutorial](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/#.UvEQRXX5PZh) that explains how to correctly incorporate Javascript in a WordPress website, but could not find a decent explanation.

I am running WordPress 3.8.1 with the [Genesis Framework](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/) and the sample child theme on my localhost, i.e. I do all edits in the `functions.php` and `style.css` of my child theme.

On the front page I would like to call some Javasript/jQuery, a fullscreen background slideshow called [Vegas](https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas).

So I created a `js`-folder in the child theme's directory, to which I copied `jquery.vegas.js` and added the following to my `functions.php`:

```
//* Adds Vegas slideshow to the front page

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_page_slideshow' );

function front_page_slideshow() {

  wp_register_script( 'jquery.vegas', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.vegas.js', array('jquery'), '1.3.4', true );

  if ( is_front_page() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.vegas');
    }

}
```

Furthermore, I added the relevant CSS-classes of `jquery.vegas.css` to my `style.css`.

My problem is that I don't know, where to place the code, that triggers the script execution. According to the [Vegas-documentation](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/slideshow/), the script executes by placing e.g. the following javascript just before the closing body-tag:

```
$.vegas('slideshow', {
  backgrounds:[
    { src:'/img/bg1.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'/img/bg2.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'/img/bg3.jpg', fade:1000 }
  ]
})('overlay', {
  src:'/vegas/overlays/11.png'
});
```

I unsuccesfully tried to place it in an additional php-file and called it with a [hook](http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/) in `functions.php` with the following:

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_footer', 'slideshow' );

function test() {
    if (is_front_page()) 
    require(CHILD_DIR.'/slideshow.php');
}
```

However, the script does not execute. I would appreciate your help and advice on this.

Comment: Have you looked for errors in your browsers javascript console?

Comment: First of all, is this the correct way, how to load and execute the script? Chrome console states the following: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'vegas' of undefined`

Comment: Does the script tag to your .js show up in the HTML? Do you get any 404 errors? `$.vegas` will not work just like this, check the jQuery noconflict implementation in the Wordpress documentation.

Comment: Yes, the script tag to the .js shows up in the HTML, so does `$.vegas('slideshow', {
  backgrounds:[ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [jQuery noConflict wrapper WordPress provides](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Instead of

```
$.vegas();
```

you have to use

```
jQuery.vegas();
```

That's why you get `Cannot call method of undefined`, because `$` is not defined in WordPress, it's called `jQuery`.

If you want to use a lot of code that uses the `$` shorthand you can use this trick to spare you rewriting everything:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
    $.vegas(); // this will work in here.
});
```

Comment: This solved the problem. The script works like a charm now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_footer', 'test' );
```

To:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'test', 100 );
```

Your JS file is loading on the WordPress footer hook whereas your JS code is loading above it. By loading your JS code on the WP footer hook as well and giving it a low priority you're ensuring it loads at the right stage.

Be sure to change the image paths by the way.

Comment: The script still does not run. The only difference is that the script-tag of th .js is pushed completely to the end of the HTML. I changed the links accordingly.

Comment: Does it appear after the JS file? Are you seeing the same issue in the console? Also in your JS are you wrapper $.vegas... in $(function() {

Comment: I modified my question by the way since your function name is test and not slideshow

Comment: HTML first displays the link to the JS file and then directly afterwards `<script> $.vegas...` Console still displays `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'vegas' of undefined` The links to the picture and to `jQuery.vegas.js` are working; the script just doesn't execute. Yes, I used test.php.